I am trying to get NLCD landscape metrics into their own column, rather than in one column
I am working with 25 years worth of capture from a lot of sampling sites, and have several years worth of NLCD data. The code that I have below is working, but it is giving me three columns: A class column (number that matches the type of landscape). A metric column (ed for edge density), area_mn for core area (supposed to be core, but I'm not worried about that right now), and lpi (for largest patch index). Then I'm getting a Value column stating the value for each metric. Instead of getting these three columns, I'm trying to get the metrics just for my Deciduous class (class 2) and my Total Forest class (class 3), and I'm trying to get each metric into it's own column (ep_deciduous, core_deciduous, lpi_deciduous, ed_forest, core_forest, lpi_forest). I've tried searching, but I don't know what to search for.
This is the current code that I have:
#List years for data compiling purposes
    years <- c(2001,2004,2006,2008,2011,2016,2019,2021)
    
    #Create empty data frame for all sites
    land.sites <- data.frame()
    
    for(s in 1:dim(sites)[1]){
      #Subset to single site and create shapefile
      s1 <- SpatialPointsDataFrame(coords = sites[s,c(3,2)], data = sites[s,])
      
      #Set projection
      projection(s1) <- CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84")
      
      #Transform to UTMs
      s2 = spTransform(s1, CRS("+proj=aea +lat_0=23 +lon_0=-96 +lat_1=29.5 +lat_2=45.5 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +datum=NAD83 +units=m +no_defs"))
      
      #Buffer site by 1000m
      sites.buffer = raster::buffer(s2, width = 1000, dissolve = FALSE)
      
      #Create empty dataframe for site
      FTC.df <- data.frame()
      
      for(r in 1:length(years)){
        
        #Crop site to raster
        s3 = crop(rast(FTC.2[[r]]), vect(sites.buffer), mask = TRUE)
        
        # Reclassify NLCD classes
        s3_reclass <- s3  # Create a new raster for reclassification
        s3_reclass[s3 %in% 21:24] <- 1  # Developed
        s3_reclass[s3 == 41] <- 2       # Deciduous
        s3_reclass[s3 %in% c(41, 42, 43)] <- 3  # Total forest
        s3_reclass[s3 %in% c(52, 71)] <- 4       # Grass
        s3_reclass[s3 %in% c(81, 82)] <- 5       # Ag.land
        s3_reclass[s3 %in% c(90, 95)] <- 6       # Wetlands
        
        #Calculate metrics {you can add more here if needed}
        ed <- lsm_c_ed(s3_reclass)        #Edge density m/ha
        core <- lsm_c_area_mn(s3_reclass) #Core area ha
        lpi <- lsm_c_lpi(s3_reclass)      #Largest patch index Approaches LPI = 0 when the 
        #largest patch is becoming small and equals LPI = 
        #100 when only one patch is present (smaller number 
        #= patches are smaller and patchier landscape; 
        #large number = single patch taking up more of the landscape)
        
        #Create data.frame
        df1 <- data.frame(Sampling_Site_ID = sites$Sampling_Site_ID[s],
                          nlcd.year = years[r],
                          Metric = c(ed$metric, core$metric, lpi$metric),
                          Class = c(ed$class, core$class, lpi$class),
                          Value = c(ed$value, core$value, lpi$value))
        
        #Bind to previous years for this site
        FTC.df <- rbind(FTC.df, df1)               
      }
      
      # Aggregate metrics by the new classes
      aggregated_df <- FTC.df %>%
        group_by(Sampling_Site_ID, nlcd.year, Class, Metric) %>%
        summarise(Value = sum(Value), .groups = 'drop')  # Summarize by summing the values
      
      
      #Bind to previous sites
      land.sites <- rbind(land.sites, aggregated_df)
    }
    
    #Merge land.sites into site_formatted_capture and match by nlcd.year
    
    site_formatted_capture <- left_join(site_formatted_capture, land.sites, by=c("Sampling_Site_ID", "nlcd.year"))

I already have a lot of other columns in my df, so I'll just give the resulting columns that matter here:



year
Sampling_Site_ID
species_code
nlcd.year
Class
Metric
Value




1998
1
species1
2001
1
area_nm
3.285


1998
1
species1
2001
1
ed
12.208


1998
1
species1
2001
1
lpi
1.692


1998
1
species1
2001
3
area_nm
75.667


1998
1
species1
2001
3
ed
32.463


1998
1
species1
2001
3
lpi
87.125


1998
1
species1
2001
5
area_nm
0.247


1998
1
species1
2001
5
ed
2.127


1998
1
species1
2001
5
lpi
0.110


1998
1
species1
2001
6
area_nm
1.086


1998
1
species1
2001
6
ed
25.527


1998
1
species1
2001
6
lpi
1.664



It just keeps repeating this format for each of my 12 species for every class of NLCD data. What I'm trying to get instead should look something like the following:



year
Sampling_Site_ID
species_code
nlcd.year
ed_forest
core_forest
lpi_forest




1998
1
species1
2001
75.667
32.463
87.125


1998
1
species2
2001
75.667
32.463
87.125


1998
1
species3
2001
75.667
32.463
87.125


1998
1
species4
2001
75.667
32.463
87.125


1998
1
species5
2001
75.667
32.463
87.125


1998
1
species6
2001
75.667
32.463
87.125


1998
1
species7
2001
75.667
32.463
87.125


1998
1
species8
2001
75.667
32.463
87.125



The code should continue to run through the rest of the years. I'm just trying to format like above, while also getting the same three columns for deciduous (class 2)
